# Correct column order for index creation in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

Consider the table `Address` with two `text` column, `City` and `State`. I will implement the following query:

```
select * from address where city = $1 and state = $2;
```

To be able to search by an index I will create an index:

```
create index address_city_state on address(city,state);
```

The question is, the order in which the columns are set in the index creation, first city than state, impact in the query performance or in any other way, considering that city values will vary more than state values?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For this query:

```
where city = $1 and state = $2
```

It doesn't matter which key goes first.  Both keys are going to be used to lookup (using an index seek) the specific row.

If `city`/`state` are *always* going to be used together and *always* with `=`, then I would probably put `state` first and then `city`, because that follows the geographic hierarchy.  However, I don't think there is any performance benefit.

If there are other potential queries, then that could affect the ordering of the keys.

The ordering of the keys matters when not all the keys have `=` comparisons in the `where` clause.  That does not appear to be the case here.

Comment: Do you have an explanation or a reference why it doesn't matter? If the index is a hash of the values of both columns, I understand that the order doesn't matter, but if the column are indexed individually, the cardinality of each column would matter, right?

Comment: @SamuelMorais . . . This refers to a b-Tree index (but it should be true for a hash index as well).  A b-Tree index is comparing all keys at once (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree).  There might be some teensy optimization when the keys are of different types, but not any real impact on performance.

Answer (score 1):

You generally would want to put the more restrictive column first in the index.  That is, if `city` had higher cardinality than `state`, then you would use `(city, state)`.  The reason for this is that it would, in theory, allow Postgres to filter off many irrelevant records first, before even hitting the second column in the index.

But, there is a problem with your query.  You are doing a `select *`, and this means that most likely your index would have to cover all the columns in the select clause, in order for Postgres to decide to use it.  If your `address` table had, for example, only two other columns, then you could use this index:

```
(city, state, col1, col2)
```

The above index is said to *cover* the third and fourth columns `col1` and `col2`, because it means that the index by itself contains all the information needed to complete the original query.  If you try `select *` and your table has many other columns, then Postgres may not use your suggested index.

Comment: Covering indexes are a nice thing, but the additional columns also inflate the index. I don't understand why you think that `SELECT *` won't work well with the two-column index.

Comment: Are you suggesting that postgres make a index per column and search them sequentially? If that is the case, why is it better to filter irrelevant records first? I think that to discard registers with lower cardnality first would be faster because you can discard larger groups. Don't worry about the `select * `, it is not what this question is about, It is also just an example.